# How to update to UiAutomator2?

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I have some Robot Framework tests for Android device which I'm running. I'm currently using Windows10 computer to develop those tests.

I just installed version v1.15.0-1 of Appium. By default this new Appium is using UIAutomator2. Not anymore UIAutomator1. My problem is, that I have installed UIAutomator2, but Appium not seem to find that. Only way I can run my tests is to use UIAutomator1.

I have installed UIAutomator2 driver:

npm -g install appium-uiautomator2-driver

Not working:

```
Open Application  ${REMOTE_URL}  platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}  platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}  appPackage=${${ENV}_APP_PACKAGE}  automationName=UiAutomator2  app=${${ENV}_APP}  appActivity=com.dummyfi.viestit.ui.splash.SplashActivity     noReset=True
```

Working:

```
Open Application  ${REMOTE_URL}  platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}  platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}  deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}  appPackage=${${ENV}_APP_PACKAGE}  automationName=UiAutomator1  app=${${ENV}_APP}  appActivity=com.dummyfi.viestit.ui.splash.SplashActivity     noReset=True
```

This is what I get, when I'm trying to run tests with UIAutomator2:

Suite setup failed:
*WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at 'fi.dummy.viestit.sa' does not exist or is not accessible*

With UIAutomator1, everything is working fine.

Comment: How did you install the libraries? If with pip, what does "pip freeze" says? Also update the robotframework-appium library just in case.

Comment: what's you mean ? by defualt uiautomator2 is included

Comment: Try removing the option `appActivity=com.dummyfi.viestit.ui.splash.SplashActivity` it may have changed what the starting activity. Also, there may be more information on the logs, before the final error message.

Comment: pip freeze says:



`Appium-Python-Client==0.40
decorator==4.4.0
docutils==0.14
kitchen==1.2.5
robotframework==3.1.1
robotframework-appiumlibrary==1.5.0.4
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.1 `

I also updated Robot Framework AppiumLibrary. No change.

Comment: @SidaraKEO Yes that is true. But I have been using version 1.13.0 version of Desktop Appium. Then I decided to update it to latest version, which is 1.15.0-1. After that, I was not able to start my tests, and only way to start them, was to change `automationName=UiAutomator1`. Otherwise UIAutomator2 was used and test could not be run. 

Now the problem is, that I have installed UiAutomator2, but still it doesn't seem to work.